# How to run full DAG multiple times instead of running each of tasks repeatedly

Tags: python, airflow

I have a DAG with multiple tasks queued into simple and straighforward dependency.

```
import datetime as dt

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator

from airflow.settings import log


def task1_cb(ds, **kwargs):
    log.info('Task1 Complete for date: %s' % kwargs.get('end_date'))


def task2_cb(ds, **kwargs):
    log.info('Task2 Complete for date: %s' % kwargs.get('end_date'))


def task3_cb(ds, **kwargs):
    log.info('Task3 Complete for date: %s' % kwargs.get('end_date'))


default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'concurrency': 1,
    'retries': 0
}

dag = DAG(
    'sample_serial_dag',
    start_date=dt.datetime(2018,9,1),
    end_date=dt.datetime(2018,9,5),
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval='@daily',
    catchup=True
)

task1 = PythonOperator(task_id='t1', provide_context=True, python_callable=task1_cb, dag=dag)
task2 = PythonOperator(task_id='t2', provide_context=True, python_callable=task2_cb, dag=dag)
task3 = PythonOperator(task_id='t3', provide_context=True, python_callable=task3_cb, dag=dag)

task1 >> task2 >> task3
```

I want it to catchup for the past dates (being run `@daily`). What I get now is Task 1 runs 5 times to catch up with 5 due dates, and when complete passes on to Task 2, which then runs 5 times, and so on.
Execution flow is following:

```
Task1 Complete for date: 2018-09-01
Task1 Complete for date: 2018-09-02
Task1 Complete for date: 2018-09-03
Task1 Complete for date: 2018-09-04
Task1 Complete for date: 2018-09-05

Task2 Complete for date: 2018-09-01
Task2 Complete for date: 2018-09-02
Task2 Complete for date: 2018-09-03
Task2 Complete for date: 2018-09-04
Task2 Complete for date: 2018-09-05

Task3 Complete for date: 2018-09-01
Task3 Complete for date: 2018-09-02
Task3 Complete for date: 2018-09-03
Task3 Complete for date: 2018-09-04
Task3 Complete for date: 2018-09-05
```

[image: Task 1 in graph completes for all the past dates before continuing to Task 2]

What I want is following:

Execution flow is following:

```
Task1 Complete for date: 2018-09-01
Task2 Complete for date: 2018-09-01
Task3 Complete for date: 2018-09-01

Task1 Complete for date: 2018-09-02
Task2 Complete for date: 2018-09-02
Task3 Complete for date: 2018-09-02

Task1 Complete for date: 2018-09-03
Task2 Complete for date: 2018-09-03
Task3 Complete for date: 2018-09-03

Task1 Complete for date: 2018-09-04
Task2 Complete for date: 2018-09-04
Task3 Complete for date: 2018-09-04

Task1 Complete for date: 2018-09-05
Task2 Complete for date: 2018-09-05
Task3 Complete for date: 2018-09-05
```

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with the `parallelism` setting ? Try to set this parameter to 1 (in airflow.cfg)

Comment: @CorentinLimier nope, setting neither `parallelism`, nor `dag_concurrency` to 1 did not help.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for that strange behavior was the `default_args` setting `depends_on_past` to **False**. I copy-pasted it from some tutorial or example code without actually noticing and knowing what it does.
As [per docs](https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/code.html?highlight=depends_on_past):

> depends_on_past (bool) – when set to true, task instances will run
>   sequentially while relying on the previous task’s schedule to succeed.
>   The task instance for the start_date is allowed to run.

Setting it to True did the trick and solved my problem.